# What is a secure way to serve API service that does not create a lot of communication overhead?

Tags: algorithm, security, hash

I had an interview few days ago, and the employer asked me about secure way to serve API service. He said

1. Each API request requires API key.
2. Each API request will request 1 single method, which takes a single parameter, and every service will work through this single method.

He wanted to see if there is a secure way for a client side to API request to the server side without exposing the API key.

I talked about general public/private cryptography, but he wanted simpler method than that.

In the end, he talked about using common hash algorithm (md5, sha1) for client side to safely hash its key, and also hash the method with parameter and request to the server, but I do not think I got the point very well.

I remember some libraries out there first encodes the body of the API request to be encrypted with md5 or sha1. But what is the point of doing it with 1-way hash? It may be true that man-in-the-middle won't know about API key, but how will server know 1.API key, 2.What method that client has requested?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if *he* didn't get the point either.

Answer (score 0):

You can hash the request together with API key. And then add the hash to the request.

That way the hash never goes over the wire. And the server can verify from his own copy of the API key.

---

For example the client does:

```
var request = "http://example.com/bla?a=1&b=2";
var hash = sha1(request + ApiKey).ToHex();
var request-with-hash = request +"&key="+hash;
```

And the server does:

```
var receivedRequest = "http://example.com/bla?a=1&b=2&key=ABC...09"
var key=extractKey(receivedRequest); // ABC...09
var strippedRequest = stripKeyFromRequest(receivedRequest);
var hash = sha1(strippedRequest + ApiKey).ToHex();
if(hash!=key)
  Error("ApiKeyWrong")
```

---

Note that this still suffers from at least two problems:

1. Replay attacks. This can be avoided by using a better protocol, with some kind of nonce.
2. The API key can be simply extract from the client, unless it's running on a secure system. This is a fundamental problem, and cannot be avoided. ApiKeys on untrusted systems are not secure.

Comment: How does `stipKeyFromRequest` works? Is that basically finding out `key` from `sha1(request+APIKey)`

Comment: find the `&key=` parameter, and remove text till you either hit another `&` or the end of string.

Comment: Whats the difference of that from `extractKey`?

Comment: `extractKey` returns the *key* part of the request(i.e. the hex string). `stripKey` returns everything *but the key*. Which should be identical to the request before the key was added.

Comment: Thanks!, but in this case, server would not know so much about which API key he has to use to compare with the request, right? If every user has its own API key, server wouldn't know about it.. I think even the employer did not get the concept of the question.

Comment: then the client can simply send an id that has a 1-to-1 mapping to the API key. Either simply something like a user name, or a hash of only the `ApiKey` itself.